# RMMapview sending touch / Gesture data from topview to bottom view

Tags: objective-c, ios, route-me, ofx

i've been trying every kind of possibility to send the touch/gesture events from the topView to the bottom view. I'm using a Open frameworks GLView. I can send the data from one class to a subclass, but the RMMapView still  doesn't override the gesture and touch events. I've tried using touch/gesture and the Hittest, but on all of them I cannot take control over the mapview. Here's where I tried to forward the pan events.

What I did in the EAGLView.h 
https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/blob/master/addons/ofxiPhone/src/EAGLView.h
layer class:

```
            UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]        initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)] autorelease];
            panGestureRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;
            panGestureRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
            [self addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];


 - (void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
            {
        NSLog(@"EAGLEVIEW Pan");

        for (UIView *view in [ofxiPhoneGetUIWindow() subviews])
        {
            if([view isKindOfClass:[RMMapView class]])
            {
                [view  handlePanGesture:recognizer];

               // [view panGestureRecognizer delegate self];
               //  [self addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
            }


        }

    }
```

https://github.com/route-me/route-me/blob/master/MapView/Map/RMMapView.m
Subclass of RMMapview:

```
    if (self) {
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)] autorelease];
    [panGestureRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    panGestureRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;
    panGestureRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
  NSLog(@"hallo123 %@",self);
    [self addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];

- (void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
    {
NSLog(@"pan");
 [recognizer setDelegate:self];
[super handlePanGesture:recognizer];
    }
```